# One button, 2 action and name change, Swift?

Tags: button, swift, action

I'm new to this field, so maybe a very simple question, I do not know, about swift. I know  how to make 2 buttons to be used for a stopwatch, start and stop. But I would like to have the same button to start and stop the stopwatch, and the text then change from stop to start, is this possible and how?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is really about Swift. This is very basic Cocoa / Foundation stuff. Have you any experience with developing for iOS / OSX?

Comment: No, I just started 3 weeks ago, have searched online but with out luck, but maybe I do not even know sufficient to search correctly!

Comment: I would suggest picking up a book or look for introductory tutorials on programming with Cocoa for iOS or OSX. There's too much ground to cover to get to what you are asking, for it to fit into an answer on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to create a simple iOS project that works with your requirements. Here is a step by step.

Create a `UIViewController` scene in your project's `Storyboard` and name it "ViewController". Add a `UIButton` with some auto layout constraints in your scene. In your Project Navigator, create a `UIViewController` subclass file with the following code in it:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    var timer: NSTimer?
    var myInt = 0

    var launchBool: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if launchBool == true {
                myButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: .Normal)
                timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "fireStopWatch", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            } else {
                myButton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
                timer?.invalidate()
                timer = nil
                myInt = 0
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        launchBool = !launchBool //true to false, false to true...
    }

    func fireStopWatch() {
        myInt += 1
        println(myInt)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myButton.setTitle("Start", forState: .Normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Link your `@IBAction` and `@IBOutlet` to the `UIButton` in your ViewController scene. Launch your project.

Each time you click on your `UIButton`, it toggles its title between "Start" and "Stop". Each time you click on "Start", it displays the increasing value of `myInt` in your Xcode console. Each time you click on "Stop", it stops your `NSTimer` and resets `myInt` to 0.